# Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-info:processReleaseResources'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Excus me.. can anyone help me.., i want install package react-native-device-info into my project, but i get some issue with this package, off course i have already use react-native link react-native-device-info suitable on procedure react-native-device-info.
but i still get this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-
info:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to run this command in your terminal:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

evidently i'm just need to remove my SDK, and download it again

Thank You all :)